# how to know the table name of a partition in pg_partition for postgresql

Tags: postgresql, partition

i check partition information from pg_partition,

```
select 
relname,
parttype,
parentid,
rangenum,
interval,
boundaries
from pg_partition where parttype='p';
```

the problem is: how to know where these partitions comes from,

Comment: There is no [system table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html) `pg_partition` in Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using *greenplum*, `pg_partitions`  has a `tablename` column. See [**This answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820312/psql-select-size-of-tables-for-both-partitioned-and-normal)

For Postgres, the name of the table that stores partition info is [**`pg_partitioned_table`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/catalog-pg-partitioned-table.html)

For table details that contain partitions, you may simple query `pg_class` as in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/223403/136182)

```
select c.relnamespace::regnamespace::text as schema,
       c.relname as table_name, 
       pg_get_partkeydef(c.oid) as partition_key
from   pg_class c
where  c.relkind = 'p';
```

Here's a [**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b8dfc297b8b13ad0e4e847c14e4fe463)

If you want all the information of partition and their tables, you may combine the 2 tables as in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/223333/136182)